# Multi selections in progressive rendering parallel coordinate d3 V4?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to make a parallel coordinate by using progressive rendering, similar to this example https://bl.ocks.org/syntagmatic/05a5b0897a48890133beb59c815bd953

I made a simpler version like this http://plnkr.co/edit/62aXey7lSqvaAJ0R7Kwv?p=preview. Is there a way so that we can do multi selections on an axis, for example brushing 0.1 to 0.3 and again 0.6 to 0.8 on same column1 axis, same holds for other axis as well.

I tried modifying the actives array in the code, but it seems it takes just one brushing area per axis.

Please feel free to ask for any clarifications.
Any help would be highly appreciated.
Thanks

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Nutrient Parallel Coordinates IV</title>

<style>
body {
  min-width: 760px;
}




.parcoords {
  display: block;
}

.parcoords svg,
.parcoords canvas {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
  position: absolute;
}

.parcoords canvas {
  opacity: 0.9;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.axis .title {
  font-size: 10px;
  transform: rotate(-21deg) translate(-5px,-6px);
  fill: #222;
}

.axis line,
.axis path {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #ccc;
  stroke-width: 1px;
}

.axis .tick text {
  fill: #222;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.axis.pl_facility .tick text,
.axis.pl_instrument .tick text,
.axis.st_spstr .tick text {
  font-size: 6px; 
}

.axis.pl_telescope .tick text {
  font-size: 5px; 
}

.axis:hover line,
.axis:hover path,
.axis.active line,
.axis.active path {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #222;
  stroke-width: 1px;
}

.axis:hover .title {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.axis:hover .tick text {
  opacity: 1;
}

.axis.active .title {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.axis.active .tick text {
  opacity: 1;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.brush .extent {
  fill-opacity: .3;
  stroke: #fff;
  stroke-width: 1px;
}

pre {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 6px 12px;
  tab-size: 40;
  font-size: 10px;
  overflow: auto;
}

</style>
<body>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>

<script>
var renderQueue = (function(func) {
  var _queue = [],                  // data to be rendered
      _rate = 1000,                 // number of calls per frame
      _invalidate = function() {},  // invalidate last render queue
      _clear = function() {};       // clearing function

  var rq = function(data) {
    if (data) rq.data(data);
    _invalidate();
    _clear();
    rq.render();
  };

  rq.render = function() {
    var valid = true;
    _invalidate = rq.invalidate = function() {
      valid = false;
    };

    function doFrame() {
      if (!valid) return true;
      var chunk = _queue.splice(0,_rate);
      chunk.map(func);
      timer_frame(doFrame);
    }

    doFrame();
  };

  rq.data = function(data) {
    _invalidate();
    _queue = data.slice(0);   // creates a copy of the data
    return rq;
  };

  rq.add = function(data) {
    _queue = _queue.concat(data);
  };

  rq.rate = function(value) {
    if (!arguments.length) return _rate;
    _rate = value;
    return rq;
  };

  rq.remaining = function() {
    return _queue.length;
  };

  // clear the canvas
  rq.clear = function(func) {
    if (!arguments.length) {
      _clear();
      return rq;
    }
    _clear = func;
    return rq;
  };

  rq.invalidate = _invalidate;

  var timer_frame = window.requestAnimationFrame
    || window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame
    || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame
    || window.oRequestAnimationFrame
    || window.msRequestAnimationFrame
    || function(callback) { setTimeout(callback, 17); };

  return rq;
});

</script>
<script>

var temp = [];

var actives_test = [];


var margin = {top: 66, right: 110, bottom: 20, left: 188},
    width = document.body.clientWidth - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 340 - margin.top - margin.bottom,
    innerHeight = height - 2;

var devicePixelRatio = window.devicePixelRatio || 1;

var color = d3.scaleOrdinal()
  .domain(["Radial Velocity", "Imaging", "Eclipse Timing Variations", "Astrometry", "Microlensing", "Orbital Brightness Modulation", "Pulsar Timing", "Pulsation Timing Variations", "Transit", "Transit Timing Variations"])
  .range(["#DB7F85", "#50AB84", "#4C6C86", "#C47DCB", "#B59248", "#DD6CA7", "#E15E5A", "#5DA5B3", "#725D82", "#54AF52", "#954D56", "#8C92E8", "#D8597D", "#AB9C27", "#D67D4B", "#D58323", "#BA89AD", "#357468", "#8F86C2", "#7D9E33", "#517C3F", "#9D5130", "#5E9ACF", "#776327", "#944F7E"]);

var types = {
  "Number": {
    key: "Number",
    coerce: function(d) { return +d; },
    extent: d3.extent,
    within: function(d, extent, dim) { return extent[0] <= dim.scale(d) && dim.scale(d) <= extent[1]; },
    defaultScale: d3.scaleLinear().range([innerHeight, 0])
  },
  "String": {
    key: "String",
    coerce: String,
    extent: function (data) { return data.sort(); },
    within: function(d, extent, dim) { return extent[0] <= dim.scale(d) && dim.scale(d) <= extent[1]; },
    defaultScale: d3.scalePoint().range([0, innerHeight])
  },
  "Date": {
    key: "Date",
    coerce: function(d) { return new Date(d); },
    extent: d3.extent,
    within: function(d, extent, dim) { return extent[0] <= dim.scale(d) && dim.scale(d) <= extent[1]; },
    defaultScale: d3.scaleTime().range([innerHeight, 0])
  }
};




var dimensions = [

  {
    key: "column1",
    type: types["Number"],
    scale: d3.scaleSqrt().range([innerHeight, 0])
  },
 {
    key: "column2",
   // description: "Food ",
    type: types["String"],
    axis: d3.axisLeft()
      .tickFormat(function(d,i) {
        return d;
      })
  },
  {
    key: "column3",
    type: types["Number"],
    scale: d3.scaleSqrt().range([innerHeight, 0])
  },
  {
    key: "column4",
   // description: "Food Group",
    type: types["String"],
    axis: d3.axisLeft()
      .tickFormat(function(d,i) {
        return d;
      })
  },
   {
    key: "column5",
    type: types["Number"],
    scale: d3.scaleSqrt().range([innerHeight, 0])
  },

   {
    key: "column6",
    //description: "Food Group",
    type: types["String"],
    axis: d3.axisLeft()
      .tickFormat(function(d,i) {
        return d;
      })
  },


   {
    key: "column7",
    //description: "Food Group",
    type: types["String"],
    axis: d3.axisLeft()
      .tickFormat(function(d,i) {
        return d;
      })
  },

  ];


var xscale = d3.scalePoint()
    .domain(d3.range(dimensions.length))
    .range([0, width]);

var yAxis = d3.axisLeft();

var container = d3.select("body").append("div")
    .attr("class", "parcoords")
    .style("width", width + margin.left + margin.right + "px")
    .style("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom + "px");

var svg = container.append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var canvas = container.append("canvas")
    .attr("width", width * devicePixelRatio)
    .attr("height", height * devicePixelRatio)
    .style("width", width + "px")
    .style("height", height + "px")
    .style("margin-top", margin.top + "px")
    .style("margin-left", margin.left + "px");

var ctx = canvas.node().getContext("2d");
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'darken';
ctx.globalAlpha = 0.15;
ctx.lineWidth = 1.5;
ctx.scale(devicePixelRatio, devicePixelRatio);

//var output = d3.select("body").append("pre");

var axes = svg.selectAll(".axis")
    .data(dimensions)
  .enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", function(d) { return "axis " + d.key.replace(/ /g, "_"); })
    .attr("transform", function(d,i) { return "translate(" + xscale(i) + ")"; });

d3.csv("data.csv", function(error, data) {
  if (error) throw error;

  data.forEach(function(d) {
    dimensions.forEach(function(p) {
      d[p.key] = !d[p.key] ? null : p.type.coerce(d[p.key]);
    });

    // truncate long text strings to fit in data table
    for (var key in d) {
      if (d[key] && d[key].length > 35) d[key] = d[key].slice(0,36);
    }
  });

  // type/dimension default setting happens here
  dimensions.forEach(function(dim) {
    if (!("domain" in dim)) {
      // detect domain using dimension type's extent function
      dim.domain = d3_functor(dim.type.extent)(data.map(function(d) { return d[dim.key]; }));
    }
    if (!("scale" in dim)) {
      // use type's default scale for dimension
      dim.scale = dim.type.defaultScale.copy();
    }
    dim.scale.domain(dim.domain);
  });

  var render = renderQueue(draw).rate(30);

  ctx.clearRect(0,0,width,height);
  ctx.globalAlpha = d3.min([1.15/Math.pow(data.length,0.3),1]);
  render(data);

  axes.append("g")
      .each(function(d) {
        var renderAxis = "axis" in d
          ? d.axis.scale(d.scale)  // custom axis
          : yAxis.scale(d.scale);  // default axis
        d3.select(this).call(renderAxis);
      })
    .append("text")
      .attr("class", "title")
      .attr("text-anchor", "start")
      .text(function(d) { return "description" in d ? d.description : d.key; });

  // Add and store a brush for each axis.
  axes.append("g")
      .attr("class", "brush")
      .each(function(d) {
        d3.select(this).call(d.brush = d3.brushY()
          .extent([[-10,0], [10,height]])
          .on("start", brushstart)
          .on("brush", brush)
          .on("end", brush)
        )
      })
    .selectAll("rect")
      .attr("x", -8)
      .attr("width", 16);

  d3.selectAll(".axis.pl_discmethod .tick text")
    .style("fill", color);

  //output.text(d3.tsvFormat(data.slice(0,24)));

  function project(d) {
    return dimensions.map(function(p,i) {
      // check if data element has property and contains a value
      if (
        !(p.key in d) ||
        d[p.key] === null
      ) return null;

      return [xscale(i),p.scale(d[p.key])];
    });
  };

  function draw(d) {
    ctx.strokeStyle = color(d.pl_discmethod);
    ctx.beginPath();
    var coords = project(d);
    coords.forEach(function(p,i) {
      // this tricky bit avoids rendering null values as 0
      if (p === null) {
        // this bit renders horizontal lines on the previous/next
        // dimensions, so that sandwiched null values are visible
        if (i > 0) {
          var prev = coords[i-1];
          if (prev !== null) {
            ctx.moveTo(prev[0],prev[1]);
            ctx.lineTo(prev[0]+6,prev[1]);
          }
        }
        if (i < coords.length-1) {
          var next = coords[i+1];
          if (next !== null) {
            ctx.moveTo(next[0]-6,next[1]);
          }
        }
        return;
      }

      if (i == 0) {
        ctx.moveTo(p[0],p[1]);
        return;
      }

      ctx.lineTo(p[0],p[1]);
    });
    ctx.stroke();
  }

  function brushstart() {
    d3.event.sourceEvent.stopPropagation();
  }

  // Handles a brush event, toggling the display of foreground lines.
  function brush() {
    render.invalidate();

    console.log("brushing");

   var actives = [];
    svg.selectAll(".axis .brush")
      .filter(function(d) {
        return d3.brushSelection(this);
      })
      .each(function(d) {
     // console.log("d", d);
        temp.push(d);
        actives.push({
          dimension: d,
          extent: d3.brushSelection(this)
        });
      });



      console.log("actives", actives);

    var selected = data.filter(function(d) {
      if (actives.every(function(active) {
          var dim = active.dimension;
          // test if point is within extents for each active brush
          return dim.type.within(d[dim.key], active.extent, dim);
        })) {
        return true;
      }
    });

    // show ticks for active brush dimensions
    // and filter ticks to only those within brush extents
    /*
    svg.selectAll(".axis")
        .filter(function(d) {
          return actives.indexOf(d) > -1 ? true : false;
        })
        .classed("active", true)
        .each(function(dimension, i) {
          var extent = extents[i];
          d3.select(this)
            .selectAll(".tick text")
            .style("display", function(d) {
              var value = dimension.type.coerce(d);
              return dimension.type.within(value, extent, dimension) ? null : "none";
            });
        });

    // reset dimensions without active brushes
    svg.selectAll(".axis")
        .filter(function(d) {
          return actives.indexOf(d) > -1 ? false : true;
        })
        .classed("active", false)
        .selectAll(".tick text")
          .style("display", null);
    */

    ctx.clearRect(0,0,width,height);
    ctx.globalAlpha = d3.min([0.85/Math.pow(selected.length,0.3),1]);
    render(selected);

    //output.text(d3.tsvFormat(selected.slice(0,24)));
  }
});

function d3_functor(v) {
  return typeof v === "function" ? v : function() { return v; };
};
</script>
```